# Facebook invite friends to Use Android App

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am little bit confused about new api and app review steps of facebook api. I need to have facebook login and get the list of friends of a logged in user and sent invitation to use app for selected friends. What are the steps i should follow it? do i need to submit my app for review in facebook?

Answer (score 1):

You can´t get all the friends of a user anymore, at least not for an Android App. You only get the friends who authorized the App too.

There is [invitable_friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/invitable_friends) for inviting friends, but:

> The Invitable Friends API is only available to apps classified as Games, which also have a Canvas presence. This API is not available in v1.0. It may be called by mobile games as long as they also have a Canvas presence.

You may want to read this too: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

Answer (score 0):

Facebook change there api police. if you do not get Friends to send invitation. if you want to do that then you need to submit your app for review by facebook team but if your app is Game then you able to do that.

But another way, you can do that, You can do it via facebook web-dialog to send invitation.

Thanks

Comment: do we get the fbuserids in using facebook web-dialog?